# RegEx compliance for every URl except specific string included

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

I would like to customize the currency of the URL if it does not match the country via URL rewriting.

My current rewrite rule on Apache looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/(.*)_DE/(?!.*(EUR))(.*)$" "https://localhost/$1_DE/EUR$2"
```

Thus the URL https://localhost/de_DE/USD would have to be changed to https://localhost/de_DE/EUR, but unfortunately the rule does not apply.

Is there a web tester for Apache RegEx? regex101.com does not seem to be exact for Apache.

Comment: Your current regex seems a bit off, it should have no `^` in the middle, something like `^/(.*)_DE/(?!.*EUR)(.*)$`

Comment: Yes there was a typo. Thanks. But the second question would still be useful for more rewrite rules. Is there a web tester for apache regex?

Comment: Probably https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: I think regex101 should be OK if you choose Python flavor.

Comment: regex101 has no matches for regex ^/(.*)_DE/HRK(.*)$ and string https://localhost/de_DE/HRK , but  htaccess.madewithlove.be works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Final RegEx is:

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/(.*)_DE/((?!.*EUR)[A-Z{3,3}]+)(.*)$" "https://localhost/$1_DE/EUR$3"
```

Thanks for your help an the websit